# Object has no attribute 'text' when parsing xml

Tags: python, xml, celementtree

I'm using ElementTree to parse a simple string of xml:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">maison</string>
```

That's the root. All I want is the contents of that tag, to convert into json. 'translation' is the xml text.

```
tree = ET.ElementTree(translation)
        root = tree.getroot()

        return root.text
```

It looks simple enough but it's throwing the " Object has no attribute 'text' " error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `fromstring` to parse that xml, to get the text for this tag, do this:

```
tree = ET.fromstring(translate)
print tree.text()

'maison'
```

should also point out that `ET.ElementTree` doesn't have attribute `text`, you can read more information on this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)